# nodejs check if file content equals to '1', if not, repeat?

Tags: node.js, wait, fs

is it somehow possible to make application "wait" till conditions are true and actively re-check conditions if they are false?

```
   try {
        var test123= fs.readFileSync('file.txt', 'utf8');
        console.log(test123);    
        if (test123== '1')
        {
            console.log('test123== 1');
        //Tried return; here? Does not work
//also tried while (test123=='1') {}. also hanging out and just waiting even that i changed file.txt content to "0"
        }
    } catch(e) {
        console.log('Error:', e.stack);
    }
```

Comment: If you use `while` you must re-read the file, it will not be updated automatically

Answer (score 1):

you can/should use while instead

```
var contents
while( contents !== '1' ) {
  contents = fs.readFileSync('file.txt', 'utf8');
}

console.log('this will be executed once the interpreter exits the loop')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use either recursion or loops. I personally would prefer recursion.

```
function recrsiveCheck(fileName, flag) {
  try {
    var test123 = fs.readFileSync(fileName, 'utf-8');
    console.log(test123);
    if(test123 == '1') {
      console.log('test123 == 1');
    } else {
      console.log('test123 != 1');
    }
    flag -= 1;  // You can remove this flag check if you want it to check infinitely, similar to flag you can put other conditions to continue or stopping your checking.
    if(flag > 0) {
      recursiveCheck(fileName, flag);
    }
  } catch(e) {
    console.log('Error:', e.stack);
  }
}
recursiveCheck('file.txt', 10);
```

This would run 10 times.

Comment: Recursion is actually not really adapted to this IMO, it stacks up function contexts, using memory, and could end to a `too much recursion` error quite quickly if there is too much wait..

Comment: Are you kidding me? Recursion?? That's even used in Quick Sort, the fastest sorting algorithm. I think what you are pointing to at @Kaddath is running it infinitely, and that would be the same case for loops. Equal memory if run infinitely.

Comment: [here you are](https://tio.run/##fY29CsIwFIX3PsXdktAfHKXFyamL7xDCTY2mSUluoyA@e2ytk4JnOgc@zneRSUYVzER12uecZACCA0wYtA@jdAob529cdIWenSLjHQRUc4gm4fGM6sq1sXiSI1agrRwEPApYsvay7N5deRe9xcb6gTPXso2sgMEYW1jmJEPE3hEnqH/VQmw3X162ihu60@dvoZ7FH2Ynupxf): barely 7000 loop turns and 0.3 seconds before you get a `Maximum call stack size exceeded` error. I don't know why you mention a sorting algorithm, that's nothing to do with waiting before something completes.. You won't get this limitation with a loop

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
let res;
while( res !== '1' ) {
  res = fs.readFileSync('file.txt', 'utf8');
}
```